# Why do (short) strands of hair keep a horizontal position while falling?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, drag, stability

When I drop a short (5 to 10 cm) strand of hair, it tends to end up falling slowly down at a horizontal position.

I would expect a uniform cylinder to fall through air neutrally (at a arbitrary position), as the pressure and gravity centers coincide$^1$. And if the strand is not perfectly straight, i.e., if we can model it as a falling bow or arc, than concavity-up could be more stable - but would it be even more stable than pointing vertically down?

**Question**: why does the strand keep a (mostly) horizontal orientation as it falls?

$^1$ <sub>Check [Nakka page on rocketry](https://www.nakka-rocketry.net/fins.html) for a nice explanation and application of those concepts.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not a falling hair expert, but this behavior sounds reasonable enough so I'll take a crack at it.

The hair is short enough, thin enough, and light enough that it reaches its terminal velocity very quickly. If it were to fall vertically (so as to minimize the area with air resistance as you describe), it would pick up speed, but then because it is so flexible, the front end of the strand would become unstable and get displaced to one side exposing the next length of the strand to the oncoming air. This suggests that the most stable position of the hair as it falls is to be horizontal with each piece of the strand experiencing equal air resistance.

Comment: I guess now you are a falling hair expert.